# Can I use more than one variables.tf file in Terraform?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform

I have declared all of my variables inside the single variables.tf file .

But I want to fetch the AWS AMI ids dynamically.

So, I am trying to create a second variables.tf file (variables-amis.tf) dynamically via a Python script that uses Boto to fetch the latest AMI ids based on a name tag.

As I have read in the documentation, Terraform will use every `.tf` file that will find in the working path.

Can I break the variables file into smaller ones?

Am I over engineering in some way? Is there a simple and more elegant way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terraform will concatenate all the `.tf` files in the folder together so, yes, you can simply have variables defined in other files.

One thing to bear in mind is that since 0.7 Terraform will error if a variable is defined in multiple files in the folder that is being worked on.

So if you had something like this:

```
terraform
├── configuration.tf
├── main.tf
└── variables.tf
```

And variables.tf contained:

```
variable "foo" { default = "foo" }
variable "bar" { default = "bar" }
```

and configuration.tf contained:

```
variable "foo" { default = "bar" }
```

This would cause Terraform to error because the `foo` variable is defined twice.

In your specific situation however, instead of writing a Python script to find an AMI based on a tag you might be better off using the [`aws_ami` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html).

Terraform's data sources allow you to pass dynamic configuration in by querying a remote data source. This could be a script or remote state stored in some backend such as S3 or in this case you could just query the AWS API using the `aws_ami` data source.

A brief example (from Terraform's [`aws_instance` docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html)) would be something like this:

```
data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }
  filter {
    name = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
    ami = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    tags {
        Name = "HelloWorld"
    }
}
```

This goes and finds an AMI published by the `099720109477` account (Canonical) and that has a virtualization type of `hvm` and a name beginning with `ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-*` to pull the latest official 14.04 image. It then takes that AMI and uses it to create an instance with it.

Comment: Thanks, I really missed that in the documentation!